# Translate polygon to cover at least 2 lattice points

Tags: geometry, polygons, integer-lattices

Let $S$ be a polygon (not necessarily convex) in the plane, of area greater than $1$. Show that it is possible to translate $S$ in the plane so that it covers at least $2$ lattice points.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What material are you reading? Any book? I want to know the source of this problem.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Hi, Teresa! Actually, it's from a miscellaneous problem set provided by a friend who's a freshman majoring in math. So my guess is that it does not require a very high level of proficiency in geometry and stuff.

Comment: I see! I thought the question was hard, because you have not even assumed convexity. I assumed it must be a basic result in integral geometry, maybe something using Crofton's formula, but now I am at a loss.